# Share a SESSION across django and zope application

Tags: python, django, zope

I have a problem. I am developing an application in ZOPE/python (zope 2.7) and another one using Django/python (Django 1.5). 
Both application is completely independent, is on a separate server and has an own domain. 
But they are using same database

eg: www.djangoapp.com, www.zopeapp.com

what  I need is, if a user is already authenticated to one of the site then the same user should be able to access the other site without having to authenticate again.

Please help me..

Comment: Maybe you can integrate a custom authentication backend for django. Have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends

Comment: Both Django and Zope can use custom authentication code. Plone uses this to implement [`plone.session`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.session), which is usable outside of Plone, implementing a [`mod_auth_tkt`-compatible session cookie[(http://www.openfusion.com.au/labs/mod_auth_tkt/) (cryptographically signed). If there is similar module for Django and you configure both servers with the same secret, there is no reason the authentication cannot be shared.